# Using debug with services 3

Tags: 7, services

I'm desperately trying to debug some problems I'm having with creating an manipulation of nodes in drupal 7 Services 3.

I've tried to insert a few debug statements to figure out where things are going wrong. When I create a node using poster (from the browser) it worked great, it prints the info I want.

When I do it from my app (iphone app), the same function is called, but the debug does not seem to print out to the page, even if I refresh it. I wonder what I am doing wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard debugging functions like `dpm()` and `dvm()` use the [`drupal_set_message()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_set_message) function, which is tied to a user's session. When you try using the node form, you see the message because it is saved to your session. However, when you use the service via your iphone app, the messages get saved to a session that is probably not the one you're logged in under.

Fortunately, for situations like this, you can use the `dd()` function, which will print the debugging information out to a file in the `/tmp` directory, typically called `drupal_debug.txt`.

**[edit]** I notice you're using the `debug()` function, which triggers error handling, note that this also uses `drupal_set_message()`, so the above is still relevant. (The `dpm()` and `dvm()` functions are from the Devel module.)

Comment: this is exactly what I need thanks, fyi on my system the file ends up in Applications/MAMP/tmp/php

Answer (score 1):

You could also try using `watchdog()`.

```
watchdog('debug', '<pre>'. print_r($example_array, TRUE) .'</pre>');
```